# Creating a modal dialog via button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, updatepanel

I am trying to have a button inside an update panel create a modal dialog in javascript and have it pop up the code below is what I am using. I have tried several different ways of going about this and I am just completely stuck.

```
protected void btnRequestPrint_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    var parent = button.Parent;
    var row = parent.DataItemContainer;

    var printLabel = row.FindControl("lblPrints") as Label;
    var literal = parent.FindControl("lJavascriptPrint") as Literal;
    var label = parent.FindControl("lblMessage") as Label;

    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "RequestPrint":
            var productId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            currentProduct = productId;
            var customerId = NopContext.Current.User.CustomerId;

            var ei = this.EncryptionService.GetEncryptionInfo(customerId, productId);
            if (ei != null && ei.Prints > 0)
            {
                literal.Text = @"
                        <div id=""removeME"">
                                                    <!-- yes/no dialog -->

                        <div class=""modal"" id=""yesno"">
                            <h2>
                                Did your music print correctly?</h2>
                            <p>
                                &lt;--Printing Instructions for your browser will go here--&gt;</p>
                            <!-- yes/no buttons -->
                            <p>"
                            //<asp:Button runat=""server"" ID=""btnPrintDialogYes"" CssClass=""close btn btn-primary""
                            //    Text=""Yes"" OnClick=""btnPrintDialogYes_Click"" />
                            //<asp:Button runat=""server"" ID=""btnPrintDialogNo"" CssClass=""close btn btn-danger""
                            //    Text=""No"" />
                        +
                        @"
                        <button onclick=""absorbPrint(" + currentProduct + @")"" class=""btn btn-primary close"">Yes</button>
                        <button class=""btn btn-danger close"">No</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>";
           string UtilsScript = @"
                        <script type=""text/javascript"">
                            function absorbPrint(id) {
                                $.ajax({
                                  type: ""POST"",
                                  url: ""checkoutdownload.aspx/absorbPrint"",
                                  data: ""{}"",
                                  contentType: ""application/json; charset=utf-8"",
                                  dataType: ""json"",
                                  success: function(msg) {
                                    console.log(""success"");
                                  }
                                });
                            }

                            var yesnoDialog = $(""#yesno"").dialog({
                                modal: true
                            });
                            $(""#yesno .close"").click(""function() {
                                $(""#yesno"").dialog(""close"");
                            });
                        </script>";
                    var upanel = parent.Parent as UpdatePanel;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upanel, upanel.GetType(), "PrintSong", UtilsScript, false);

            }
            else
            {
                label.Visible = true;
                label.Text = "No prints available";
                button.Visible = false;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The markup (this is inside of a gridview):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlNonFolio" runat="server" Visible='<%# ! IsProductFolio( (int)Eval("ProductId")) %>'>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlInstantPrint" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRequestPrint" CssClass="btn btn-primary modalInput"
                            Text="Print" CommandName="RequestPrint" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>'
                            OnCommand="btnRequestPrint_Command" />
                        <asp:Literal ID="lJavascriptPrint" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage" Visible="false" />
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlFolio" runat="server" Visible='<%#  IsProductFolio( (int)Eval("ProductId")) %>'>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIsFolio" Text="This Product Is A Folio" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I can try to paste more code if necessary it's just private code so I can't paste some of it.

So anyhow, currently when I am doing this I am getting the following error upon click the print button:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
Type.registerNamespace('Sys.WebForms');Sys.WebForms.Res={"PRM_UnknownToken":"Unknown token: \u0027{0}\u0027.","PRM_MissingPanel":"Could not find UpdatePanel with ID \u0027{0}\u0027. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.","PRM_ServerError":"An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: {0}","PRM_ParserError":"The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.\r\nDetails: {0}","PRM_TimeoutError":"The server request timed out.","PRM_ParserErrorDetails":"Error parsing near \u0027{0}\u0027.","PRM_CannotRegisterTwice":"The PageRequestManager cannot be initialized more than once."};
```

Comment: Are you getting any javascript error before you click the button?

Comment: Update panels are pure evil;

Comment: No errors prior to clicking the button.

Comment: It turns out I just had an extra "" in the javascript portion. It's working fine for this portion now. I am having another issue but I will post that separately as it has nothing to do with this.